# Three.js rotate camera to specific position

Tags: css, three.js

I have an sphere with divs using CSS3DRenderer. When I click to one of the divs I'd like to position/rotate the camera so the element displays in the center of the screen.
I've tried several examples and I've read other answers but still I cant get it to work.

At the moment it moves the camera but the sphere gets repositioned in different places

What I'm trying to do is the following:

Gets the HTML element's class. Then loop through an array of THREE.CSS3DObject to get its position, then use that to position the camera.

```
function moveCamera(element) {

for ( var i = 0; i < objects.length; i ++ ) {

    var object = objects[ i ];

    if(object.element.className == element.className) {

        position = object.position;
        rotation = object.rotation;
        found = true;
        break;
    }

}

if (found) {

    camera.rotation = rotation;
    render();
    found = false;

} }
```

What I'm I doing wrong?

Here's the example http://jsfiddle.net/37R22/1/

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close. You just have to move the camera to the right place.

```
camera.rotation.copy( rotation );
camera.position.copy( position ).multiplyScalar( 4 );
```

Updated fiddles: http://jsfiddle.net/37R22/2/ or http://jsfiddle.net/37R22/3/

Be careful about going behind-the-back of `TrackballControls` and modifying the camera properties yourself. This appears to work, however.

three.js r.65

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works perfectly, although I don't understand the theory behind it...